# Setting the default date in Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS version 4.7.14.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

For some reason the control is ALWAYS using the current date and time.  I've tried useCurrent: false, defaultDate, setDate and several other options all to no avail. It does not pick up the value in the input box either.

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field From must be a date." data-val-required="The From field is required." id="periodBegin" name="periodBegin" type="datetime" value="03/09/2015 04:11 PM">

$('#periodBegin').datetimepicker({format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a'});

var periodBegin = moment('2/8/1956 3:30 pm');
$('#periodBegin').datetimepicker({defaultDate: periodBegin });
```

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 1):

When calling moment(string) it is recommended to provide a format as well, when possible.

```
moment('02/08/1956 03:30 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A');
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

There is also a slight mismatch with the format in your example, as "03/09/2015 04:11 PM" should be "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A" not "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a". See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/spasticdonkey/87b4y96g/4/